# ActiveRecord AssociationTypeMismatch in rails 4 app, but works fine in version 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ahoy

I was working on a ruby on rails 4 app , in which I installed a gem called 'ahoy' for usage analytics.

It is giving an error of

```
" ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#70304630869100) expected, got Hash(#6226260))"
```

at `visit.rb`.

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :ahoy_dev
  has_many :ahoy_events, class_name: "Ahoy::Event"
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have figured out that when `"optional :true"` is added to the line `"belongs_to :user"` it is working fine in Rails 5 version app.

But the app which I want to implement this is Rails 4. When optional :true is added to the line 
`belongs_to :user` in Rails 4, it shows syntax error that `'optional'` is not an allowed keyword.

Any idea how to sort out this issue , if I cannot upgrade the app to Rails 5 now ?

Comment: Where is the error raised? Can you show the code that assigns the Hash to the `user` association?

Comment: Error is raised at the server side.

Comment: belongs_to associations is where the error is raised. The assignments are taken care by the gem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried ?

> belongs_to :user, required: false